# How to set it so that a layout on top of a bottom sheet behavior dynamically changes its height when the bottom sheet is expanded?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm very new to Android app development and am trying to create custom keyboard which is within a bottom sheet. After making the keyboard I wanted to add a scrollview on top of the bottom sheet in which all the main content will be. But as soon as I put a scrollview on top of the bottom sheet, the bottom sheet gets locked and can no longer get expanded. My knowledge in the field is not the best, but I could not find any solution to this problem I'm facing so I would love any help I can get. I am using Android Studio for the development for reference. This is also my first time using stack to get a question answered so I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information.
[Sample code which I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9Tx.png)
Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you're new to Android development, Keyboard is not the right place to start with as it is quite complicated to make a good keyboard app that could be used instead of the default app. Do not use screenshots to include code, refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I'd also recommend adding the code for the relevant java/kotlin files as xml files just have the layout information.